# Cat command Unexpected delimited by end-of-file

Tags: shell, unix

I have the script

```
#!/bin/bash
set i=0;
while read line
do
  echo "$line";
  $i < cat "my.log" | grep -w "$line" | wc -l;
  echo "$i";
  if [ "$i" == 0 ]; then
  cat $line << "notfound.txt"
  fi
  i=0;
done < "test.txt"
```

which is giving the error

```
./test.sh: line 13: warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `notfound.txt')
./test.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

My goal is to test the value of the variable i. If it is 0 then I would like to redirect the value stored in the variable $line to a file "notfound.txt"

Comment: Unrelated to your stated problem, but `$i < cat "my.log"` is likely to be a problem - `i` is a variable with the initial value of `0`, and never gets changed (although it gets reassigned), so that will expand to `0 < cat "my.log"`. Unless your system has a command called `0`, this will likely fail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
cat $line << "notfound.txt"
```

say:

```
echo $line > "notfound.txt"
```

You don't `cat` variables, you `echo` those instead.  `command > file` would redirect the output of the *command* to the *file*, overwriting it.  If you want to *append* the file, use `>>` instead.

You can learn more about redirection [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

Comment: Thank you. I have just replaced > with >> as I need the values to be appended to the existing file. I'll accept your answer as soon as stackoverlow lets me :-)